# Bootstrap Carousel Returning Database Item List But Not Looping Through List

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, bootstrap-5

I've an alert list which displays messages to users on screen, however instead of displaying the messages one at a time through using a carousel, all 3 messages are being displayed at the same time.

Please see code below. How can I loop through the list to only display one message at a time within the carousel?

**View**

```
<div id="alertCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    @{
        int i = 0;
    }
    @foreach (var item in (List<BusinessCaseManagementSystem.Models.Alert>)ViewBag.newAlert)
    {
        i++;
        var active = i == 1 ? "active" : "";
        <div class="item @active" style="text-align:center;width:100%">
            <span>@item.Message</span>
        </div>


        // first = false;
    }
</div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#alertCarousel" data-slide="prev" style="background-image:none">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" style="color:dodgerblue"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>


<a class="right carousel-control" href="#alertCarousel" data-slide="next" style="background-image:none">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="color:dodgerblue"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

**Controller Action**

```
 public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //Alert Carousel
        List<Alert> alertList = _db.Alert.ToList();
        ViewBag.newAlert = alertList;

        return View();
    }
```

**jQuery**

I also tried implementing this but no luck

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function(){
        var $active = $('#alertCarousel li.active');
        var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#alertCarousel li:first');
    $active.fadeOut(function(){
        $active.removeClass('active');
        $next.fadeIn().addClass('active');
    });
}, 2000);
  
});
```

Comment: Try using classes correctly: `<div class="carousel-item">` , also `data-bs-ride="carousel"`-> see doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working by changing the code within my View. The only issue that remains is that it delays showing the first item for a few seconds, instead of it appearing immediately when the pages loads.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            var $active = $('#carouselExampleInterval li.active');
            var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#carouselExampleInterval li:first');
            $active.fadeOut(function () {
                $active.removeClass('active');
                $next.fadeIn().addClass('active');
            });
        }, 2000);


    });

</script>

<div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide card text-bg-primary" style="height:100px" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <h3 style="text-align:center">
        <i class="bi-info-circle" style="font-size: 1.5rem; color: white;">
            Information
        </i>
    </h3>
    <ul class="carousel-inner">

        <li class="carousel-item active">
            @foreach (var item in (List<BusinessCaseManagementSystem.Models.Alert>)ViewBag.newAlert)
            {
                <div class="carousel-item" style="text-align:center">
                    <h5><span>@item.Message</span></h5>
                </div>
            }
        </li>

        <li class="carousel-item">
            @foreach (var item in (List<BusinessCaseManagementSystem.Models.Alert>)ViewBag.newAlert)
            {
                <div class="carousel-item" style="text-align:center">
                    <h5><span>@item.Message</span></h5>
                </div>
            }

        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```